# Using awk or shell to total values in a delimited file

Tags: file, awk, sum, numbers, append

I have a pipe delimited file that also has delimited values in certain fields and I want to get the total of the 37th field and have it added to end of each line

Sample file looks like this
1|2|18|45324.56|John|Smith|...etc then the 37th field has |1.99^2.46^79.87|next data field here|etc

I want to add the numbers 1.99, 2.46, 79.87 together and add them to the end of the file

1|2|18|45324.56|John|Smith|...etc then the 37th field has |1.99^2.46^79.87|next data field here|84.32 <- total of all values in $37  (this field can have 1 value or over 100 values in it

Obviously I can do  awk 'F'|' '{print $37}' file and it will show me 1.99^2.46^79.87 but I'm uncertain how to total those values since it's basically delimited data inside of differently delimited data

Edit here is full line of data

1|12|15|29786.31|test|true|2019-12-01|2021-02-28||2019-12-01|2021-02-28|1417.00|t0000000|John|Smith|current|1234 Main St|Dallas|TX|75000|Office|8709999999||||||||Attachment^Attachment|t0000000_4042 - Application Documents.pdf^t0000000_4042 - Lease Agreement.pdf|704405808^704405809^704405810^704523038^704523039^704523593^704523594|2021-03-01^2021-03-01^2021-03-01^2021-02-28^2021-02-28^2021-03-06^2021-03-06|RUBS Income  Water/Sewer^RUBS Income  Water/Sewer^Utility Bi
lling Revenue^Damages/Cleaning Fees^Damages/Cleaning Fees^RUBS Income  Water/Sewer^RUBS Income Water/Sewer|Charge^Charge^Charge^Charge^Charge^Charge^Charge|18.25^15.26^2.99^40.00^25.00^18.88^15.78|18.25^15.26^2.99^40.00^25.00^18.88^15.78|Charge Code^Charge Code Desc^Transaction Note^Charge Code^Charge Code Desc^Transa
ction Note^Charge Code^Charge Code Desc^Transaction Note^Charge Code^Charge Code Desc^Transaction Note^Charge Code^Charge Code Desc^Transaction Note^Charge Code^Charge Code Desc^Transaction Note^Charge Code^Charge Code Desc^Transaction Note

Comment: *I want to add the numbers 1.99, 2.46, 79.87 together and add them to the end of the file* end of file (total for all lines in new line after these lines) or end of line (adding new column with sum for each line)?

Answer (score 1):

awk has a function `split` that splits a field on some delimiter:

```
awk -F\| '
    split($37, a, "^")             # split on caret, store in a
    s = 0; for (i in a) s += a[i]  # sum values
    print $0 "|" s                 # append new column and output
' sample_file
```

Comment: it may be worth noting: 1) order of elements returned by `(i in a)` is arbitrary and may not match the order of the data; 2) `split` operates on regex, not string; oddly, `"^"` (match literal caret) is not the same as `/^/` (match start of string) so beware